# how to get single column from two columns having same value and null?

Tags: sql, postgresql-8.2

Hi how do i get single column from two columns in postgresql as my column outputs are:

```
Column 1     Column 2
a            a     
b              
c            c
```

or

```
column 1    column 2
a            a
             b
c            c
```

should get output as below

```
column
a
b
c
```

Tried concatenating but it joins table as i don't want to join columns

Answer (score 0):

You should probably research SQL a bit, as for your question I believe `union` with `distinct` will do the job

```
select distinct(foo.foo) from(
select column1 as foo from your_table where column1 is not null
union 
select column2 as foo from your_table where column2 is not null) as foo;
```

See [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/97fef/1)